# Change image tag shown in `docker ps`

Tags: docker

I have a container running from a given image.

This image has multiple tags.

If I remove the image tag shown in `docker ps`, `docker ps` will show the image digest instead of an image tag.

If I then tag the image with a new tag, `docker ps` will continue to show the digest.

How do I get `docker ps` to display a new or different image tag for a given container using that image?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way. You need to run a new container from the image with new tag.